# How to set page title by page id in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to set the page title in wordpress.

Suppose in a blog centered site, whenever we click a tag, a new page is opened with all the posts of that tag. I cannot set page title for these pages.

There should be a solution to that problem, that is like adding filter to set page title by page ids. I mean whenever pages with specific ids open, it should show custom title. How can I do this?

Comment: [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_title#Customizing_with_the_filter)

Answer (score 0):

I've encounterer the same problem i made this :

```
 <?php $tag_name = get_tags(array('slug'=>get_query_var('tag'))); ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) :  ?>



                    <div <?php post_class(array('pin-article')); ?> >



                        <article class="article category">

                             <p><?php _e( 'Tag','wip'); ?> : <strong> <?php echo $tag_name[0]->name;  ?> </strong> </p>

                    </article>



                    </div>

             <?php if ( $wp_query->post_count > 1 ) : ?>



                          <div class="filter" data-filter="all"><?php _e( 'Show all','wip' ); ?></div>

                          <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                          <?php $mixitTags = get_the_tags();?>  

                                <?php foreach($mixitTags as $k => $tag):

                                          if($tag->name != $tag_name[0]->name):

                                             $tagFilter[] = $tag->name;



                                          endif;

                                 endforeach;?>

                          <?php endwhile;?>

                          <?php 

                          $tagFilter = array_unique($tagFilter);



                          foreach ($tagFilter as $filter) :

                            echo '<div class="filter" data-filter=".'.sanitize_title($filter).'">'.$filter.'</div>';

                          endforeach ?>

              <?php endif; ?><!-- Fin de vérification si post > 1 -->
```

Comment: Hi @Xam1311, I think you didn't underdstand my problem. I want change the page title of the archive pages. By different seo plugins, you can change page title for manually created pages but not for automatically generated pages like tag/category archive pages. I want to change title of a archive page.